# Default Database name in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

badly need help here. I have a website hosted in wordpress.com. I played around with the wp-config.php file and changed this line.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'mydatabase');
```

I have uploaded this and now everytime I load my website it says "Error establishing a database connection". I was not able to remember the database name, is there a default database name for wordpress? Note that my website is not local, it's already online. (http://european-supplement-shop.com/)

Comment: Do you have access to your website's control panel? You can check the database via the phpAdmin section.

Comment: no, every time I access any part of my website is always an error with "Error establishing a database connection".

Comment: I don't mean the backend of your website, I mean the control panel of your hosting company where your website is hosted. Can you access this?

Comment: no I dont have the access of the host. :(

Comment: Can you contact them to find out what the database is, as it's usually wp_ and then some numbers. There's no default title unfortunately, unless you set it yourself on first installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALl you have to do is to get the name of the database from the control panel of your hosting and if its not set then give a name to the database and then change the name in wp-config.php

Answer (score 1):

When installing a new version of Wordpress, the database is usually automatically given the suffix wp_ and then a series of numbers. This is an arbitrary number, so won't actually have any relation to anything in your install.

If you don't have access to your host's control panel, you will need to contact them to find the database name. Make sure you have some way of identifying yourself as the owner of the domain before calling as they will need to verify you are who you say you are before providing this information.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a default database name for WordPress. WordPress provides the files, where as you (or your host) provides the database. If you didn't create the database yourself, then contact your hosting company to find out the database name.

Answer (score 0):

As both Ronan and hery point out there is no default name for WordPress-databases.

However, looking at your [hosting provider's website](https://www.strato.de/), it seems that you can only find the db name by logging in here:

https://www.strato.de/apps/CustomerService

(I know you say that you don't have a login but I sense by the comments that it *might be* lost in translation).

I base my answer on [this](http://www.strato-faq.de/artikel.html?articleid=746).